# A faster way for caching values for a hash

Tags: ruby, hash, default-value

With `Hash.new` taking a block, it is possible to create a cache as follows:

```
cache = Hash.new do |hash, key|
  hash[key] = expensive_calculation(key)
end
```

Why is it so complicated?

```
cache = Hash.cache do |key|
  expensive_calculation(key)
end
```

Such a version would be faster because only one argument is passed to the block. From my experience, this makes quite a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposal implies that the block is evaluated only once per key, and its value is cached for the key.

However, that is not the only way to use this feature. One may want to calculate the value more than once for the same key. In your proposal, that cannot be done. It lacks flexibility.